# iPhone Check Empty dictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary

```
if ([dict objectForKey:@"photo"] !=(id)[NSNull null]) 
    {NSLOG(@"dictinary is not empty")}
```

This is not working for me. to check empty tag

Comment: photo key is a string or number value?

Comment: You are confusing `NSNull` with `NULL`.  The former is used to insert null objects into a null terminated array, while the latter is used to check if an object exists or not.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `count`.

For example:

```
if ([dict count] == 0) {
     NSLog("empty");
}
```

If you want to check for a key then:

```
if([dict objectForKey:@"photo"]) {
    NSLog(@"There's an object in photo");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me. You can handle Null with this code.

```
[dict isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `objectForKey:@"photo"` is null when not present you can just do: `if ([dictionary objectForKey:@"photo"]) {NSLog(@"dictionary is not empty);}`

Comment: Yes, it is. This is a best practice way to do an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for check is null value or not

```
NSString *value=[dict objectForKey:@"photo"];

if (value.length != 0 )
{
  NSLog("not empty!");
}
else
{
  NSLog("empty!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken into the string like :

```
 NSString *strPhoto=[dict objectForKey:@"photo"];

if (strPhoto ==(id)[NSNull null] || [strPhoto isEqualToString:@""] || strPhoto==nil || [strPhoto length]==0) {
}
```

It is working for me !!!!!!!!!!